# How add some text from gradle.build to Android studio (or IDEA) Live Templates?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, build.gradle, live-templates

For example: I added gson library import to Live Templates, but it doesn't work.

http://screencast.com/t/UTaxqmHlr

http://screencast.com/t/m1ZdSvdT0JkJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check groovy in Live Templates

http://screencast.com/t/ELFMPxGA